# efeito sanfona lado a lado

Tags: css

vou ter varias sanfonas no site, conforme as categorias, ai coloquei elas lado a lado, so que quando eu clico em uma das sanfonas, as que esta do lado gera um espaçamento indesejavel, queria saber como resolver isso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML**

```
 <div class="seg-nt">
    <div class="caixa">
        <span class="open-nt">esportes</span>

        <div class="contentNT hide">
            01
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caixa">
        <span class="open-nt">politica</span>

        <div class="contentNT hide">
            02
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caixa">
        <span class="open-nt">policial</span>

        <div class="contentNT hide">
            03
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.show{display: block;}
.hide{display: none;}
.seg-nt{
   padding: 00.80906148867314% 00.80906148867314%;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.seg-nt .caixa{
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   margin: 0% 00.80906148867314% 00.80906148867314% 0%;
   padding: 00.80906148867314% 00.80906148867314%;
   width: 49.55555555555555%;
   border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   border-radius: 3px;
}

.seg-nt .caixa:nth-child(-n+2){margin: 0% 00.80906148867314% 00.80906148867314% 0%;}
.seg-nt .caixa:nth-child(2n){margin: 0% 0% 00.80906148867314% 0%;}
.seg-nt .caixa:last-child{margin: 0%;}

.seg-nt .caixa span{
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 30px;
   font-size: 1.3em;
   text-align: center;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.seg-nt .caixa .contentNT{
   float: left;
   height: 150px;
   border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
   background-color: orange
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function(){
  $('.open-nt').click(function(){
    var contentNT = $(this).parent().find('.contentNT');
        if(!contentNT.hasClass('show')){
        $('.caixa').find('.show').slideUp('fast', function(){
            $(this).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
        });
        contentNT.slideDown('fast', function(){
            $(this).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: E qual seria esse espaço indesejado? Como vc quer que seja o comportamento quando uma delas estiver aberta?

Comment: @hugocsl opa hugo, editei a imagem, quando a sanfona esportes estiver aberta, a sanfona finanças teria que subir e preencher aquele espaço, e assim pra todas as sanfonas, conforme a qual estiver aberta

Comment: Cara tentei simular seu problema aqui mas o código da pergunta está muito distante do que está na imagem que vc postou... Vc está usando açgum framewrok tipo Bootstrap? Ou essa sua "sanfona" é algum plug in de jQuery com CSS extra e tudo mais?

Comment: opa hugo, so tem a biblioteca jquery nele, olha o problema aqui https://jsfiddle.net/moya2018/Lhcz2e7p/14/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara vc pode usar `column-count` para fazer isso, pois assim o browser "equaliza" a distribuição do conteúdo em duas colunas por exemplo. Repare que o browser sempre vai tentar igualar a altura das duas colunas, assim ele vai jogando o conteúdo sempre para onde tem espaço sobrando.

Não sei se esse é exatamente o resultado que vc espera, mas com css foi a única forma que encontrei... Deixei um comentário no código css

```js
$(function(){
    $('.open-nt').click(function(){
        var contentNT = $(this).parent().find('.contentNT');
            if(!contentNT.hasClass('show')){
            $('.caixa').find('.show').slideUp('fast', function(){
                $(this).addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
            });
            contentNT.slideDown('fast', function(){
                $(this).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.show{display: block;}
.hide{display: none;}
div{width: 100%;}
.seg-nt{
   padding: 00.80906148867314% 00.80906148867314%;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
 }

.seg-nt .caixa{
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   margin: 0% 00.80906148867314% 00.80906148867314% 0%;
   padding: 00.80906148867314% 00.80906148867314%;
   width: 325px;
   border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   border-radius: 3px;
}

.seg-nt .caixa:nth-child(-n+2){margin: 0% 00.80906148867314% 00.80906148867314% 0%;}
.seg-nt .caixa:nth-child(2n){margin: 0% 0% 00.80906148867314% 0%;}
.seg-nt .caixa:last-child{margin: 0%;}

.seg-nt .caixa span{
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 30px;
   font-size: 1.3em;
   text-align: center;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.seg-nt .caixa .contentNT{
   float: left;
   height: 150px;
   border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
   background-color: orange
}
/* separa o conteúdo em 2 colunas */
.seg-nt {
  column-count: 2;
}
/* evita que o conteúdo da caixa se quebre começando em uma coluna e terminando na outra */
.caixa {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="seg-nt">
    <div class="caixa">
        <span class="open-nt">esportes</span>

        <div class="contentNT hide">
            01
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caixa">
        <span class="open-nt">politica</span>

        <div class="contentNT hide">
            02
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caixa">
        <span class="open-nt">policial</span>

        <div class="contentNT hide">
            03
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="caixa">
        <span class="open-nt">esportes</span>

        <div class="contentNT hide">
            01
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caixa">
        <span class="open-nt">politica</span>

        <div class="contentNT hide">
            02
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caixa">
        <span class="open-nt">policial</span>

        <div class="contentNT hide">
            03
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--seg-nt-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando Bootstrap: adicione a

```
<objeto class="p-0 m-0"/>
```

se não estiver usando o bootstrap: no adicione o item

```
margin:0px !important;
padding: 0px !important;
```

a classe que utilizada pelo elemento.
ou

```
style="padding:0px !important; margin:0px !important;"
```

Todos os items vao ficar só ocuparao o espaço nessessario.

Comment: se era isso que você queria, marque a resposta como aceita